# Best way to run webpack-dev-server when developing rails app using docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This is my `docker-compose.yml` for my Rails app.
As you can see from the `command:`, I put the `rails s` into background then run `webpack-dev-server` so that my assets get compiled quickly during development.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && 
      bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0' & ./bin/webpack-dev-server"
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file: .env
    # For byebug to work
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

This worked fine for me, until I want to debug using byebug. When I `docker attach` it just doesn't give me console to interact. And so I have to comment out the  `& ./bin/webpack-dev-server` part every time I debug.

So how do you usually run the webpack-dev-server when dev on docker?

Comment: I generally use `rbenv` in a non-Docker environment for day-to-day development, which gets me non-global Ruby installation and isolated gemsets without bringing Docker into it.  Then later I'll use `docker build && docker push` to build an image and eventually run it on Kubernetes, but that's not my core development setup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @DavidMaze, but I have a number of services, like sidekiq, redis, cron, and others. They are troublesome to setup again and again. So now I prefer my rails dev to be dockerized.